PyAudio Stream causes Windows Heap Corruption (-1073740940 (0xC0000374)) when reading from stream
I've been having issues with PyAudio's Stream when trying to read it.
It crashes with exit code -1073740940 which is a Windows Heap Corruption error 0xC0000374. It happens during the line where I read from the PyAudio stream like so: stream.read(chunk_size).
I have also seen it crash with -1073741819 ACCESS_VIOLATION_EXCEPTION but I cannot replicate that.
Here are two videos of me trying to spam the record key to invoke the crash:

Without Error (silent crash): https://imgur.com/VQqbbBR
With Error: https://imgur.com/Bg5r07I

No, it does not only happen when I spam it. It happens randomly, but it increases the chances of crashing when I spam it. Sometimes at the first few tries, and sometimes over a 100 tries.
I have tried using solutions from this stackoverflow question to no avail
Here is the code if anyone would like to replicate this:
Permanent Pastebin Link (https://pastebin.com/uDeBtGgv)
# pip install wave keyboard requests pyaudio sounddevice

import sys
import traceback
import wave
from pathlib import Path
from time import sleep
import keyboard
import requests
import pyaudio
import sounddevice as sd
from threading import Thread
import faulthandler

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent
sys.path.append(str(BASE_DIR))

# The key to record audio with
MIC_RECORD_KEY = "prtscn"
CANCEL_REQUEST_KEY = "delete"

def find_device_index(query: callable):
    query_results = list(
        filter(
            query,
            list(sd.query_devices())
            )
    )

    if not len(query_results): return None
    else: return query_results[0]['index']

# Change this to your mic name first for this to work. Use `sd.query_devices()` to see all device names.
MIC = find_device_index( lambda x: x['max_output_channels'] == 0 and 'Jack Mic (Realtek(R) Audio)' in x['name'] )

''' Functions '''
    

def on_press_key(_=None):

    try:
        global frames, recording, stream

        if recording: return

        print('Listening...')

        print('Recording has started.')

        frames = []
        recording = True
        stream = p.open(format=FORMAT,
                        channels=MIC_CHANNELS,
                        rate=MIC_SAMPLING_RATE,
                        input=True,
                        frames_per_buffer=CHUNK,
                        input_device_index=MIC,)
        print('opened stream')

        return print('finished press key process')
            
    except: traceback.print_exc()


def on_release_key(_=None):
    try:
        print('Stopped listening.')
        global recording, stream
        recording = False
        stream.stop_stream()
        stream.close()
        stream = None

        # if key not held down for long enough
        if not frames or len(frames) < 20:
            print('No audio file to transcribe detected. Hold down the key for a longer time.')
            return

        print('Writing audio to file...')

        # write microphone audio to file
        # This is usually a uniquely generated path, simplified for now.
        audio_path = str(BASE_DIR /  "output.mp3" )

        with wave.open(audio_path, 'wb') as wf:
            wf.setnchannels(MIC_CHANNELS)
            wf.setsampwidth(p.get_sample_size(FORMAT))
            wf.setframerate(MIC_SAMPLING_RATE)
            wf.writeframes(b''.join(frames))
        
        print("Temporarily saved to " + audio_path)

        try: Thread( target=send_audio_to_server, args=[audio_path] ).start()
        except: traceback.print_exc()
        
        return
    
    except: traceback.print_exc()    

def send_audio_to_server(audio_file):
    
    url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/process_audio'

    settings = None

    #try: settings = json.load( open('settings.json') )
    #except OSError:
        #return print("Could not open settings.json! Possibly occupied. Disregarding this request.")
        

    data = {
        'audio_file': audio_file, 
        "device_ids": [],
        "author": "listener"
        }

    print("Sending speech request to server...")

    try: response = requests.post(url, json=data, timeout=40)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: return # Dont worry about actually connecting to the server.
    except: traceback.print_exc()

    print('retrieved response. attempting to jsonify.')

    # Rest of the code is not relevant.

''' Main process '''

if __name__ == '__main__':

    faulthandler.enable()
    
    while True:
            
        CHUNK = 1024
        FORMAT = pyaudio.paInt16

        p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        if MIC is None:
            MIC = p.get_default_input_device_info()['index']

        SPEAKER = p.get_default_output_device_info()['index']

        # get channels and sampling rate of mic
        mic_info = p.get_device_info_by_index(MIC)
        MIC_CHANNELS = mic_info['maxInputChannels']
        MIC_SAMPLING_RATE = 40000

        print('Local listener is booting up...')

        frames = []
        recording = False
        stream = None

        try:

            keyboard.on_press_key(MIC_RECORD_KEY, on_press_key)
            keyboard.on_release_key(MIC_RECORD_KEY, on_release_key)

            print('Local listener is ready')

            while True:

                try:
                    if recording and stream:
                        data = stream.read(CHUNK)
                        frames.append(data)
                    else:
                        sleep(0.2)

                except:
                    traceback.print_exc()
                    exit(1)

        except:
            traceback.print_exc()
            exit(1)

Here is what the error looks like:
Windows fatal exception: code 0xc0000374

Thread 0x00005934 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\Dhruv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\connection.py", line 73 in create_connection
  File "C:\Users\Dhruv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 196 in _new_conn
  File "C:\Users\Dhruv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 236 in connect
  File "C:\Users\Dhruv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 975 in send
  File "C:\Users\Dhruv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 1037 in _send_output
  File "C:\Users\Dhruv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 1277 in endheaders
  File "C:\Users\Dhruv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 398 in request
  File "C:\Users\Dhruv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 495 in _make_request
  File "C:\Users\Dhruv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 789 in urlopen
  File "C:\Users\Dhruv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 667 in send
  File "C:\Users\Dhruv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 703 in send
  File "C:\Users\Dhruv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 589 in request
  File "C:\Users\Dhruv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 59 in request
  File "C:\Users\Dhruv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 115 in post
  File "C:\Users\Dhruv\Desktop\py\AudioProcessorWhisper\test.py", line 119 in send_audio_to_server (Referring to "try: response = requests.post(url,  json=data,  timeout=40)")
  File "C:\Users\Dhruv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 953 in run
  File "C:\Users\Dhruv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1016 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Users\Dhruv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 973 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00006464 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\Dhruv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 320 in wait
  File "C:\Users\Dhruv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\queue.py", line 171 in get
  File "C:\Users\Dhruv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keyboard\_generic.py", line 57 in process
  File "C:\Users\Dhruv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 953 in run
  File "C:\Users\Dhruv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1016 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Users\Dhruv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 973 in _bootstrap

Thread 0x00000b54 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\Dhruv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keyboard\_winkeyboard.py", line 563 in listen
  File "C:\Users\Dhruv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\keyboard\__init__.py", line 294 in listen
  File "C:\Users\Dhruv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 953 in run
  File "C:\Users\Dhruv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1016 in _bootstrap_inner
  File "C:\Users\Dhruv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 973 in _bootstrap

Current thread 0x00006be4 (most recent call first):
  File "C:\Users\Dhruv\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyaudio\__init__.py", line 570 in read
  File "C:\Users\Dhruv\Desktop\py\AudioProcessorWhisper\test.py", line 165 in <module> (Referring to "data = stream.read(CHUNK)")

Could I be doing something wrong here?
Would appreciate some guidance.

i decided to use sounddevice instead, works much better. But I still haven't been able to solve this.
